# Geckofx Elements file upload

Tags: c#, geckofx

I've been trying to do this , but I keep failing! After some digging around I found out that you can't autopopulate file input fields for security reasons, I'm working on Web Browser Automation application for testing websites!

How do I get around this?

```
<input type="file" name="fileUploadInput"  id="fileUploadInput"  
    style="cursor:pointer;z-index:999" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about what you want to do? Do you want to automatically tell the browser what picture to upload?

Comment: yes,I think telling the browser automatically upload photos or file